# How to disable text dragging inside a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a contenteditable `div`. It currently has this default behavior of allowing you to drag pieces of text around.

Chrome/Windows (the only enviroment I tested so far).

[image]

How can I disable it? Made a simple snippet for testing below:

```css
#root {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Try selecting a piece of test and drag it around the editable area</p>
<div id="root" contenteditable>Hello World
This is a contenteditable
DIV!
</div>
```

Comment: My guess: you can't. But my first question would be: why?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm building a comment box and I don't want users moving things around. Just found out it's possible. Just listen to the `ondragstart()` event and cancel it by using `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using jquery. try this.

```
$('#root').bind('dragover drop', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not using jQuery.